# How to Set Plot Position in Core Plot

Tags: core-plot

I need to draw multiple plots. How can I set the position of each plot in codes instead of setting one by one in storyboard?

The image I want to achieve is [**here**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yvahab3db8nc4d6/design.png). In this image, each small curve is a plot. So there are in total 20 x 15 small plots. I need to position and feed different data for each of them. But I don't want to set their positions one by one coz it's tedious.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to allow user interaction or frequently update the plots? If not, your best bet is to use one graph with a single plot. Render it into small images, once for each plot, changing  the data each time. Draw the images into a view laid out in your grid.

If you can't use the image approach, you'll probably run out of memory long before setting up 300 individual graphs. Instead, use one graph with a single plot space if possible. Offset and scale the data values for each plot so they appear in the appropriate section. Use as few plots as you can (one for each line style). Separate the line segments with empty (`NAN` or `nil`) data values.